# hazelcast dataSerializable - serialize array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, serialization, hazelcast

I've read through the documentation on `DataSerialization` at

http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/dataserialization.html

and have successfully written my `writeData` and `readData` methods for primitives and custom objects however I am stumped as to how to **serialize/deserialize** an array of condition objects.  Condition object being a class I have written.

```
private NEConditionInfo[] m_arryConditions

 @Override
 public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput aOut) throws IOException 
 {
     ?
 }

 @Override
 public void readData(ObjectDataInput aIn) throws IOException 
 {   
     ?
 }
```

Do I traverse the array if not `null` calling `writeObject/readObject` on every element?

Does my condition object need to be `DataSerializable` to be able to be used?

The condition object is currently `java.io.Serializable`.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hazelcast doesn't have out of the box support for arrays afaik

So for serialization, first you serialize the size and then you iterate over every item and call objectdataouput.writeObject

And for deserialization, you read the size and create an array and then you iterate over every item to call deserialize and store it in the array.

Your condition object doesn't need to be DataSerializable to be used, as long as Hazelcast knows how to serialize it. So in this case hazelcast can see that it is java.io.Serializable